# Investigate different versions of a Python package in one Python session

Tags: python

I am wondering whether it is possible to work with several versions of the same Python package in the same Python session.

For instance, say I want to investigate possible differences between Gensim-3.7.3 and Gensim-3.8.1, is the only way then to make two virtualenvs, start two separate Python sessions, save the results, and load the results into one of the sessions (or a third sessions)?

Comment: At the very least I'd say you'll need a `venv` for each version of the package.  Then my approach would be to access the specific `venv` with `subprocess` or `multithreading`.  You could run the same script against the `python` interpreter in the respective `venv` and compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

With `importlib`, a virtualenv, explicit paths and borrowing an answer from  @sebastian-rittau at [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path), two versions of a module can be loaded. Example:

```python
from importlib.util import spec_from_file_location, module_from_spec
from os.path import expanduser

name = "gensim"
paths = [
    expanduser('~/envs/gensim-3.8.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py'),
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gensim/__init__.py',
]

gensims = []
for path in paths:
    spec = spec_from_file_location(name, path)
    gensim = module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(gensim)
    gensims.append(gensim)

for gensim in gensims:
    print(gensim.__version__)
```

The result is:

```
3.8.0
3.7.3
```